# async datareader and the order of execution

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I am using Web API. I know I have to use a full async stack to get its benefits. That means the API Controller are async calls to my service and my service does async calls to my dataprovider which do async datareader for example.

I guess when I start with using async in the controller I also should do an OpenAsync() on a database connection and use only the async Non-/Query calls.

1. Is this true?
2. When I have 3 NonQueries (A) doing stuff on Table 1,2,3. When this task is finished there MUST follow 4 NonQueries (B) doing stuff on Table 1,2,3.

Can I make use of the ExecuteNonQueryAsync method for A OR do I have to fear that B will be faster executed than A which might cause inconsistent data in my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You don't **have** to use only async methods, but I recommend you mostly do when there's an async option.  But make sure those operations are truly async.
2. If you await all your async calls than the order will be the same as if you didn't use async. 
   There's a difference between parallel and async.  An async flow isn't necessarily a parallel one.

Comment: Ok I make them truly async (without await) if the business context allows this.

Comment: Wait. no. truly async does **not** mean without `async`. I encourage you to use `await` on any `async` method unless you are sure you don't need to. When i say "truly async" i mean an operation which is naturally asynchronous underline (network or I/O for example).

Comment: now you confuse me. Truly async is for me an Async operation from through the whole web stack from controller to sql data reader.

Comment: Yes.. that's ok. Because we can trust the data reader to really be asynchronous. If it's in a .Net standard library it's probably ok.

Answer (score 1):

1) False, not necessarily
2) Doesn't apply then.

By marking your actions async the apppool thread will be released for new requests and the current request is handled by a background thread.